# Create a custom filters list for Adblock+

Tags: ads, custom-lists, adblock

I've created a little `.txt` file with custom rules for adblockers.
I wish to integrate it as a normal filter list in Adblock Options (Add a different subsciption), but it fails with the message: **Failed, not a valid list**. It works well in uBlock Origin.

```
! http://chrome.murvielinfo.com/streaming_pages_rules.txt
! Title: Murviel Info streaming pages List
!
###divPanel
##.ad
##.advertisement
###divPanelAds
###countDown
###second_ads_tmp
##div[id^="floatLayer"]
###chat
###player_gaz + div
hqq.tv##div[id^="this-pays"]
hqq.tv##script[name="need_captcha"]
@@/BTVQRA6OS11SO6ARQVTB/*.php$script,domain=videomega.tv
openload.co###srtSelector
openload.co##script[src*="adblockdetect"]
voodaith7e.com##div#player_imj
voodaith7e.com##div#player_imj + div
voodaith7e.com##.jw-dock
```

I know I can easily add custom rules to Adblock, but I would like to create a custom list that one can enable with an url.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on a simple list, and I added `[Adblock Plus 2.0]` at the beginning of the list.
And it works.

```
[Adblock Plus 2.0]
! Homepage: http://chrome.murvielinfo.com
! Title: Test List
! Expires: 5 days (update frequency)
! Version: 20170211
###my-div
##.my-class
```

Maybe it will help someone...